# How to arrange values in a hashmap if i want to filter out values inbetween open and close keywords

Tags: java, hashmap

I have Unique session id for which i want values to be populated and store them in a hashmap or similar data structures. But i want to filter the values between open and close
for ex:
[image]

so i want the output as:[image]
where 1 is the unique session followed by values between open and close

Comment: What is the initial data structure used? Is the original info stored in a HashMap as well?

Comment: No the orginal info is stored in mysql db. I want to call the values from the db and store the data in the above output format.

Comment: Can you include your complete expected output of the given table?

Comment: As you can see  the above table looks similar to mysql database. I want to get unique session data (ie time, events)  to be stored  in a hash table which output should be as above  . But i want events  between open and close event.

Comment: I see, 2 open & close pairs for session 1. Anyway, why don't you iterate through the ResultSet obtained from the database, and store the results in a HashMap as per your needs? Please mention, if you are not familiar with querying the mysql database from java, or accessing the ResultSet, or looking for the manipulation logic.

Comment: i have queried all the unique session and stored in db and for event and time i dont understand how to filter the  data between open and close event for the unique session..Once filter data is store in an array i can loop for each unique session to the array of events and time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95409/discussion-between-user2473779-and-user3778684).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the exact solution you are looking for, but will nonetheless give you an idea of the approach to follow:

```
     PreparedStatement ps=currentCon.prepareStatement(query); //currentCon is the connection
     ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
     int flag=0;
     while(rs.next()){
        String event=rs.getString("event");
        if(event.equals("open"))
          flag=1;
        else if(event.equals("close"))
          flag=0;
        if(flag==1)
           //keep storing the values in the HashMap
        else
           continue;
     }
```

Hope it helps!